# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, python-cryptography

I get an error when pip builds wheels for the cryptography package.

Error:

[image: Error]

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libssl.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have already installed OpenSSL and set the environment variables as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22210069/7199817) yet the problem persists. My setup details:

- System - Windows 10
- Python - 3.8
- Pip - 19.3.1

Comment: Building cryptography on Windows is a very involved process and it should not be required unless you're attempting to install an older cryptography version. cryptography ships Python 3.8 windows wheels for cryptography 2.8+. What happens if you run `pip install cryptography` directly?

Comment: Installing it directly works fine. However, when I install it as a part of the requirements.txt, this error shows.  How should I disable the option to build wheels? What will be the consequences if I do so?

Comment: in my case it was necessary to update pip to the latest version

Comment: @dreo I have already updated Pip but it still builds wheels for the packages

Comment: Does the requirements.txt have cryptography pinned to a version < 2.8? cryptography did not ship wheels for Python 3.8 on Windows before that release (because Python 3.8 wasn't out). On other platforms it can use a special kind of wheel that works across multiple Pythons, but on Windows each Python version requires a new wheel.

Comment: @PaulKehrer The specified version for cryptography is 2.7

Comment: You will need to update that to 2.8 to resolve the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. Just updated pip and it installed without an error.

Comment: I just restarted my computer then the error was fixed. If you still have the error, update your computer then restart you computer then try to build the docker images.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Setting cryptography to version 2.8 in requirements.txt fixed the issue.

Comment: Worked for me. Encountered this when I was setting up ESP Rainmaker (CLI Setup)

Answer (score 52):

In my case (windows 10 + conda) updating pip fixed the problem:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: docs say to upgrade pip and you'll use the distributed binary https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust

Answer (score 49):

TLDR;

Try using `cryptography==3.1.1`

Details:

This happened on `Python 3.9.0` on `Windows 10` PC.
I had the following in requirements.txt

```
cryptography==2.8
```

I removed the version and kept only cryptography in *requirements.txt* file like below

```
cryptography
```

Saved the *requirements.txt* and then I ran

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It installed successfully.
Then I freeze the *requirements.txt* by running the following command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then the *requirements.txt* got updated with `cryptography==3.1.1`

Comment: I am getting below error:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: have you followed the approach mentioned?

Comment: Yes @navule, I followed all the steps.

Comment: Try upgrading pip and re-run the steps mentioned above. To upgrade pip run `python -m pip isntall -U pip`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I was using snowflake-connector-python 2.2.8 version and it caused the issue. After removing this version number, application ran successfully. I'm not sure how will it behave once published to cloud. Hoping for the best

Comment: They started using Rust in v3.4, so to avoid Rust the latest version you can use is `cryptography==3.3.2`

Comment: @Igor Jerosimić thx man, this is the only answer that makes sense and acutally helps out. Navule just changes versions randomly w/o having any kind of expanation.

Comment: You can also try setting environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`

Comment: cryptography==40.0.2

Answer (score 35):

Had also this issue. If you're using alpine, make sure that all dependencies for cryptography are installed.
In my case the cargo package was missing and causing the issue.

```sh
sudo apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo
```

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-cryptography-on-linux

Comment: For Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev cargo`

Answer (score 19):

I faced this issue on macOS Monterey (version 12.2.1) Apple M1 Pro. I followed [Cryptography installation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/) documentation and it helped me resolve the issue.

`brew install openssl@1.1 rust`

`env CRYPTOGRAPHY_SUPPRESS_LINK_FLAGS=1 LDFLAGS="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/libssl.a $(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/libcrypto.a" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include" pip3 install cryptography`

Comment: Thank you !! This is what was blocking me on M1 Mac Pro, this resolved it !!

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue on my M1 chip

Comment: Works as a charm with M2 chip too. Thanks!

Comment: This was the answer for me, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Ran into this issue, and the solution is actually in the message when pip attempts to install openssl before cryptography:

```
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c'
  running build_rust
  
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
      5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
         set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
```

Simply running the pip update command appeared to work for me:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Which updated pip from version 18.0 to version 21.0.1

Answer (score 8):

You can use the lastest version with

```
python3 -m pip install --no-use-pep517 cryptography
```

worked for me with ubuntu:18.04 on arm32v7
(instead as suggested by the error message install the full rust compiler and build-essentials, or upgrading pip (what had no effect on ubuntu:18.04 on my armbian))

Comment: ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project specifies a build backend of setuptools.build_meta in pyproject.toml

Comment: worked for me in latest mac OS. MOnterey 12.3.1 (21E258)

Answer (score 8):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Try to upgrade pip of your environment working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error trying to install Scrapy with Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10, but its solved installing the last version of pip (19.3.1 in my case) and all works using pip in this way:

```
python -m pip install scrapy --user
```

Comment: Thanks. This also worked for me. My system is Windows 10, Python 3.8.2, Pycharm, and netmiko didn't install from Pycharm's requirement.txt file. I got inside the venv, and run pip install cryptography , which didn't work either. Then I tried python -m pip install cryptography , and it installed without any problem. Afterwards, I got back to Pycharm requirements file, and clicked on netmiko entry to get it installed, and it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue and tried to install openssl with mentioned step but still was not able to proceed for windows 10. Later I upgraded pip to latest version and tried again and it worked without any issue.

I would recommend to upgrade pip to latest version and give a try before proceeding for installing openssl

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to upgrade the pip in my tox directory to enable tox to set up my dependencies. For reference, I'm using OSX Big Sur, python 3.8, and upgraded both pips from 20.3.3 to 21.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install cryptography==3.1.1 package instead of cryptography 35 version.

```
pip install cryptography==3.1.1
```

If still you are facing challenges in cryptography package integration.

You can resolve that by the following steps.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

sudo pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. pip3 version was 19.*  after upgrade it works

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i just installed rust and problem fixed for me
You can install end version of cryptography after installing rust programming languege(dont try pip install rust, its not python package)
https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install

Answer (score 0):

Just updating pip

---

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

I did not install the latest version of Scrapy, then it worked for me. Instead of installing version 2.6.3, I installed 2.6.2:

```bash
pip install Scrapy==2.6.2
```

I use PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Professional Edition) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your fabulous suggestions. The following worked for me:

Environment - Windows 10, Python 3.7.6
The issue occurred when data was written onto MS 365 Web Excel.
Steps undertaken,

1. python -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. pip install msal

Have a good one!
Thx