# Pycharm installing sshtunnel package

Tags: python, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to install the package named `sshtunnel` but I'm getting the followig error:

```
Error ocurred when installing package 'shhtunnel'
```

And it shows the following when I click on details:

[image]

I have seen that I need to change cryptography version but I don't know how do it
How can I install it?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441794/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-cryptography-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-i)

Comment: @kandroidj No, I don't know how set cryptography to version 2.8

Answer (score 0):

First of all, upgrade your pip to the latest version and try to install sshtunnel. If this could not solve your problem then set cryptography to version 2.8 using the following command:

`pip install cryptography==2.8`